# Android Studio modules.xml how force it to be project relative?

Tags: android, module, environment-variables, build-process, android-studio

We have a weird problem on my team. It seems for some of us, when we add a module to our Android Studio project, it adds the reference in modules.xml using the $PROJECT_DIR token, but for others it adds it using the $USER_HOME token, which is not what we want.

Does anybody know how to force Android Studio to use $PROJECT_DIR in modules.xml?